# how to generate multiple charts in android

Tags: java, android, charts

How to draw multiple charts in android and I need to view it either by scroll or next button,
In my case I have used a third party to draw my chart it works well for single chart but it get overriden in case of multiple charts getting generated

---

I need pie charts like
http://w2davids.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/capture-rgraph-webview2.png

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would do better if you just did a google search for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebView with float: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Example: http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing